# ViewPager gallery in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a problem. I am trying to make slideshow gallery using ViewPager inside ListAdapter and inide ListView. Everything is ok, but only when i set ViewPager height as 300dp (example), but when i use match_parent or wrap_content it not showing content at all.

My Adapter:

```
public class KlasztorListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<KlasztorElement> {

private Activity context;
private List<KlasztorElement> klasztorElements;



static class ViewHolder
{
    public ViewPager viewPager;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View rowView = convertView;

    if(rowView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_klasztor, null, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.viewPager = (ViewPager) rowView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewHolder.viewPager.setId(position + getCount());
        viewHolder.indicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder); 
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    final KlasztorElement klasztorElement = klasztorElements.get(position);


    CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(context, klasztorElement.getImages());

    viewHolder.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewHolder.indicator.setViewPager(viewHolder.viewPager);

    return rowView;
}

class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ImageGroup> imageGroup;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageGroup> imageGroup) {
        this.imageGroup = imageGroup;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageGroup.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_image_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageGroup.get(position).getImage());
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageUtils.showImage((FragmentActivity)context, imageGroup.get(position).getImageFull());
            }
        });


        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
}
```

My element for slideshow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inner_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:src="@mipmap/klasztor_2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My ElementRow layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

</com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  // it works when i use ex. ="220dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me i have no idea how to make it works. Solution with hardcoded height works, but it will look not so good on some devices.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `ListView`s in Android don't support the `match_parent` attribute for their child elements. In addition to that the `ViewPager` doesn't support the `wrap_content` attribute, so using those two components you're pretty much stuck with using a fixed height.

If you're willing to go the extra mile though, the `RecyclerView` from the support libraries has added support for `match_parent` for its child elements. This will require some restructuring of your code though, and depending on how far you have come you might choose to do or not do this. You can find a quick tutorial on the Android Developers page for [creating lists ands cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView%20Creating%20Lists%20and%20Cards) if you're interested. If you need further explanation just ask in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I check it and i see it is looks very similar as list view. View -> Adapter -> done. So maybe it will be not so much to do.

Comment: @PawełBryś Yes, the concepts are quite similiar, so it's basically just a lot of refactoring. In the end it's up to you though. Let me know how it works out :)

Comment: I change my code for RecyclerView but i still don't know how to make it works. I set ViewPager height to match_parent and still not show image.

Comment: Did you also change the height of the wrapping `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`? By the way, I would avoid the usage of `fill_parent` as that attribute does the same as `match_parent` and is left over from an older Android version.

Comment: Oh, something is showing. But not exacly how i want. It is not fill from right to left, but now i see images!!! Thank you a lot. I write when i figured out how to do that ;D

Comment: I give up.... It cannot be done. View Pager is just stupid. When i set match_parent it fits for layout (layaout has match_parent). But when i use wrap_content it has 0dp height.